# how to add value within certain intervals only python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and values in a columns ranges from -1 to 1. I want to add 0.1 to all value between -1 to 0.6 only. Is it possible to do it?
suppose a is my list:

```
a = ([-1. , -0.5,  0.1 , 0.2, 0.45,  0.7, 0.64, 1])
```

and I want this:

```
([-0.9, -0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.55, 0.7, 0.74, 1])
```

Comment: Yes that is possible. You can write a program to do so. If you run into problems, post what  program you have as a question.

Comment: Not 100% sure if it would work over dataframes, but how about something like `[i+0.1 for i in a if -1<=i<=0.6]`? Do note that in your example, you change 0.64 to 0.74 even though that's above 0.6

Comment: @numbermaniac yes it works. If you post as an answer then i can accept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
a = [-1. , -0.5,  0.1 , 0.2, 0.45,  0.7, 0.64, 1]
a = [x + 0.1 if -1 <= x <= 0.6 else x  for x in a]
print a
```

Results:

```
[-0.9, -0.4, 0.2, 0.3, 0.55, 0.7, 0.64, 1]
```